# Why does Go use ^ rather than ~ for unary bitwise-not?

Tags: go, syntax, operators, conventions

Most programming languages use `~` to represent a unary bitwise-not operation. Go, by contrast, uses `^`:

```
fmt.Println(^1)  // Prints -2
```

Why did the Go designers decide to break with convention here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because ^x is equivalent to m ^ x with m = "all bits set to 1" for unsigned x and  m = -1 for signed x. [Says so in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_operators).

It's similar to how -x is 0 - x

Answer (score 1):

`^` operator is similar to `+` and `-` operators. For example:

```golang
+x == +0x0 + x
+x ==  0x0 + x

-x == -0x0 - x
-x ==  0x0 - x

^x == ^0x0 ^ x
^x ==  0xF ^ x
```

So `^0 ^ x` is equal to `^x`.

`^0` doesn't change the value of `^x` in `^` operation in a similar manner that `+0` doesn't change the value of `+x` in `+` operation.